# Django collectstatic : is it possible to access static files that are outside of Django Project?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to access the static files from my django app to the static files that are outside of my django app.
I want to copy or access the files in UIUX/static to DjangoRepo/myapp/static.
it looks like below

```
UIUX/
 - static
  - staticfile...
 - templates
  - index.html
DjangoRepo/
 - myapp
  - static
  - templates
```

my setting file

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# trying to access the static file outside of django file 
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    #os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/'),
    "C:/Users/kevin/workspace/UIUX/static"
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

when I run `python manage.py collectstatic` I get this

```
Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\iact80h\.virtualenvs\lynx-ocr-python-services-6157-7DFxjqs2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\iact80h\.virtualenvs\lynx-ocr-python-services-6157-7DFxjqs2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\iact80h\.virtualenvs\lynx-ocr-python-services-6157-7DFxjqs2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\iact80h\.virtualenvs\lynx-ocr-python-services-6157-7DFxjqs2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\iact80h\.virtualenvs\lynx-ocr-python-services-6157-7DFxjqs2\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 188, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "C:\Users\iact80h\.virtualenvs\lynx-ocr-python-services-6157-7DFxjqs2\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 105, in collect
    for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
  File "C:\Users\iact80h\.virtualenvs\lynx-ocr-python-services-6157-7DFxjqs2\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\finders.py", line 131, in list
    for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
  File "C:\Users\iact80h\.virtualenvs\lynx-ocr-python-services-6157-7DFxjqs2\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\utils.py", line 23, in get_files
    directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
  File "C:\Users\iact80h\.virtualenvs\lynx-ocr-python-services-6157-7DFxjqs2\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 315, in listdir
    for entry in os.scandir(path):
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] 指定されたパスが見つかりません。: 'C:\\Users\\kevin\\workspace\\lynx-ocr-python-services-6157\\C'
```

is it even possible to access the static files that are outside of the project ?

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to access static files that are outside of Django Project?

Yes! You might want to read about [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) from the Django's official documentation.

---

Study the below code:

```
my_str = (
    'My Str'
)
print(type(my_str))    # Prints: <class 'str'>

my_typle = (
    'My Tuple',
)
print(type(my_typle))    # Prints: <class 'tuple'>
```

---

`STATICFILES_DIRS` needs to be a `list` (or `tuple`), not a `str`.

So, try changing:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    #os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/'),
    "C:/Users/kevin/workspace/UIUX/static"
)
```

To:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    #os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/'),
    "C:/Users/kevin/workspace/UIUX/static",    # Note the , at the end.
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: can I ask one more question if you dont mind ? Other question is that Can I access directly to UIUX/static/ without copying it ?

Comment: Ideally, you should ask one separate question. That way it will be helpful for the community.